# Return the first 3 items that have a given property in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, limit, v-for

I'm learning vue.js by doing and I'm trying to make a store locator.

I have markers (stores) that have some properties such name and if it is a 'featured' location (true/false)...

so I do this

```
`<template v-for="featured in featuredLocations"> 
     <div v-if="featured.featured_location == true">
          <Featured 
             :name="featured.name"
             :image="featured.image"
             :facebook="featured.facebook_url"
             :twitter="featured.twitter_url"
             :featuredLocation="featured.featured_location"
          />
     </div>
</template>`
```

and ...

```
`computed: {
     featuredLocations: function(){
          return _.orderBy(this.markers, 'name') // order A-Z
     }
}`
```

This I know is looping through the markers and only displaying them if they are featured ones, however, what I really want to do is a loop through the featured ones and only show the first 3. I'm not sure how to do that, but I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the lodash [`take`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#take) function:

```js
computed: {
  featuredLocations: function(){
    let featured = _.filter(_.orderBy(this.markers, 'name'), marker => marker.featured_location)
    return _.take(featured, 3)
  }
}
```

Note: with a filter function on your computed property, you don't need the `v-if="featured.featured_location == true"` condition anymore

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!